# Python - create dataframe from output returned from a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, pygooglenews

Below is my code utilizing pygooglenews to scrape Google News:

```
def get_titles1(search):
    news = [] # list of articles that will have NLP applied to it
    search = gn.search(search, when = '2y') #when: duration; 2y = 2 years, 6m = 6 months, etc. 
    search_items = search['entries'] # list of articles retrieved before NLP
    for item in search_items: # go through all of the items in search_items
      
      try:
        url = item.link
        article = Article(url, config=config)

        article.download()
        article.parse()
        authors = ", ".join(author for author in article.authors) 
        title = article.title
        date = article.publish_date
        text = article.text
        image = article.top_image
        videos = article.movies
        url = article.url

        article.nlp()
        keywords = article.keywords
        print("\n")
        print(item.link)
        print(f"Keywords: {keywords}")
        print(f"Summary: {article.summary}")

        report = {'title':article.title, 'link':article.link, 'published':article.published}
        news.append(report)

      except:
        pass
    
    return news

data = get_titles1('Los Angeles')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Although I everything works when with the function and when I call it using the data variable, when trying to make a DataFrame, the result is empty. This is strange given that in the function, I created the result dictionary, which 'title', 'link', and 'published' all acting as column headers.

Does anybody know what is the issue? Please let me know as I am a beginner with Python. Thank you!

Comment: bare `try/except` mask any error you have in your code, Remove the try/except and see what error you get.

Comment: `except:pass` is not something anyone should ever do. Change it to `except Exception as e: print(e)` and see the error